# how do i make a vertical scrollbar using the jQuery UI .slider()?

Tags: jquery, slider, scrollbar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #slider { margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slider").slider( "option", "orientation" );

        //getter
        var orientation = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "orientation" );
        //setter
        $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "orientation", 'vertical' );
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="slider"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I added in the

```
    //getter
    var orientation = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "orientation" );
    //setter
    $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "orientation", 'vertical' );
```

part of the code in hopes of getting the demo page's scrollbar to show up vertical but all it did was hide the horizontal scrollbar that was already there and now i just have a blank page. How exactly do I implement the vertical scrollbar option? I don't quite understand the instructions listed on the [documentation page.](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Slider#event-slide)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical) part of the doc is rather clear :

```
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });
```

You juste have to do `$( "#slider" ).slider( { "orientation" : "vertical"} );` to create a vertical slider.

Comment: I actually did just this, but it is still rendering horizontally, and i cannot interact with the control more than the mouse over. I can retrieve the value out of the slider with the getter method, and it returns the correct value.

Comment: I found my issue. due to some CSS hell, a "top" style was being applied to the css class I was using to find the div that I was using for the slider. once I removed the "top" style from the css class, the slider worked correctly